# Is there an official/complete list of all US government agency "developers' pages"?

Tags: data-request, usa, government, data.gov, api

[The FCC's developers page](http://www.fcc.gov/developers) happens to have a sidebar linking to many other US government agencies' developers pages, APIs, etc. It's a handy list, but I assume the FCC hosts it only out of the goodness of their hearts (and only as time allows)---surely it's not within the FCC's scope to track this sort of thing.

Is there any other agency or office that keeps an official and/or complete list of government agency developers' pages?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is most comprehensive list of all .gov /Developer pages compiled by Gray Brooks at GSA
http://gsa.github.io/slash-developer-pages/

You can suggest new additions if some info is missing. It is currently well maintained.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry, that looks solid. It seems plausible that maintaining this list might be in the GSA's scope. But do you know whether that's true, or whether it's another unofficially-compiled list like the FCC's?

Comment: It is definitely official list (it is GSA's official GitHub account) and they make an effort to keep it well maintained (hence mechanism for suggestions if anything is missing). It is the best alternative we have (and /developer pages are fluid, so it is hard to be 100% complete). Also one can "easily" build out their own version by using USG agencies info API and just poking at every single agency.gov/developers pages.

Comment: What do you mean by official, @civilstat?

Comment: official in this case - the list provided by US government as authoritative source for this data, e.g. master list of all /developers pages that is maintained and of high quality

Comment: FYI - this is a more comprehensive list - http://www.data.gov/developers/page/developer-resources

Answer (score 3):

As someone who drives the maintenance of the listing that Dmitry mentions, I want to echo the call for folks to contribute any developer hubs that aren't listed there.  It was built and is kept up in part by significant googling for key phrases like: 'api site:.gov' or 'json site:.gov' and then going through 20-30 pages of results.  Please do help [add to the list](https://github.com/GSA/slash-developer-pages/issues?state=open), though.

[Disclaimer - I am a Sr. API Strategist at GSA]

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the [Data.gov Developer Page](http://www.data.gov/developers/), which should contain the comprehensive list of developer pages and U.S. government APIs.